# Different domain names to site languages

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, domain-access

I have a [Multilingual Drupal 7 site](http://litebook.eu). The site is in 3 languages Dutch (default), English and German. The multilingual setup is done based on the [i18n module](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n). All is setup and works great!

Dutch site: litebook.eu
German site: litebook.eu/de
English site: litebook.eu/en

But now i have 2 more Domain names i have to use: *litebook.de* and *litebook.co.uk*

I want:
- *litebook.de* to go to litebook.eu/de
- *litebook.co.uk* to go to litebook.eu/en

What is the best way to set this ups and what do i have to do exactly?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simple way will be to use .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^litebook.de$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.litebook.de$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://litebook.de/de/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^litebook.co.uk$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.litebook.co.uk$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://litebook.eu/en/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks. And what is the other way?

Comment: you can also you Drupal Redirect model "https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect" please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I will accept. And do you know what is the [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module for? Is this module handy to use in my case or is it for something else? Thanks

Comment: I never used it before but it seems to be active module a lot of site reported using it.

Comment: What i try to understand is: What is Domain Access module different then using redirect method? Thanks

Comment: I have never used it so i can really comment about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt to complete the previous answer, specific to the extra comment by OPer added to it, which is "***What is Domain Access module different then using redirect method***" ...

- "using redirect method" is like instructing the browser with something like so: "*If somebody enters an URL like, then do not display the content located at that URL; And instead, display the content of the redirected URL*".
- The [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module is used (as mentioned on its project page) for:

  > running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation and a **single shared database**. The module allows you to share users, content, and configurations across a group of sites.

  Obviously, the redirect method has nothing to do with such "sharing" ... The redirect method doesn't know anything about such sharing of databases. Maybe one could say also "doesn't even care why the content of some other URL is to be shown as a replacement of the redirected URL".